# How to remove certain UML labels in Visio 2010

Tags: uml, microsoft-visio-2010

I am trying to draw a UML diagram and have become frustrated at the inclusion of some unwanted labels (see circled in red below) when I add composition relationships. When I select them and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> I get the following message:

> Shape protection, container, and/or
>   layer properties prevent complete
>   execution of this command

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While the statement in the answer above is true it is not the solution to the problem. Most of the UML shapes have a wide variety of display options. To remove the decorations on a UML connector do the following:

1. right-click the shape
2. Select "Shape Display Options..." from the menu
3. Un-check End Options ' "First end name", "Second end name" and "End multiplicities"
4. (Alternative) In this case you might select Suppress / "First end" and "Second end". Checking the "End Options" turns things on; checking "Suppress" turns things off.

Play around with the other UML shapes to see how they behave.

Comment: Is there a way to reposition the text labels on certain UML shapes?  I want to move some labels on my sequence diagram messages?

Comment: Responding to @B Johnson: on the home ribbon, in the tools section, the tool at the bottom of the right column is an A inscribed in a 270-degree arc ending in an arrow head.  This allows you to move, resize and rotate text independently of the shape to which it is attached.

Answer (score 3):

That label is probably grouped with other items and cannot be removed.

See if this Microsoft article helps :

[Visio: Cannot Ungroup or Modify an Object in Visio](https://web.archive.org/web/20090219203950/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305343)

Comment: The steps outlined in your link worked! Thanks!

Comment: [*On the **Window** menu...*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305343). There is no Window menu!

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the **Auto assign name to newly created UML model element** option in the **UML Options** dialog (UML `->` Drawing Options), Visio will not assign meaningless names to the ends anymore.